# Web App seems to trigger mobile device colour temperature differently?

Tags: android, web-applications, frontend

I have a very strange problem with my web app seemingly triggering a colour adjustment from the android device - normally colours are fairly vibrant, in the same Chromium based browser for other pages, but once switched to my web app, the screen's colour temperature turns cool, and saturation seems to be toned down, resulting in a dull grey looking page.

Other pages within my web app doesn't seem to trigger this colour profile change.

I cannot think of what possibly might be causing this. Is this solely something done by the device, and not possibly controlled by me, or is there something that can be done for the front-end code? This is a web app, and not a native app, so I can't access android APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possibly the mobile view of the website? I've seen websites have a poorly optimized mobile view, causing similar issues.

Comment: How would a mobile view trigger a colour profile change? There would be image assets that are the same regardless of mobile vs desktop. It looks like the device colour profile has been applied across the entire screen, not just on the page.